# Iterate through a list using rxjava2

Tags: android, arraylist, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a list of Custom objects (`List<Item> itemsList`). Here's my custom class :

```
public class Item {
    private String itemId;
    private String itemName;
}
```

The initial list has only itemName; itemId will be empty. I want to iterate through the list and add an itemId for each item and then with the new list, I need to do some sort of long operation with each items in the list.

```
for(Item item : itemsList){
item.setitemId = getUniqueId(); //getUniqueId() returns an unique id
doSomeLongOperation(item);
}
```

I'm a newbie in rxjava operators. Please help me out with how to achieve the same using rxjava2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `Observable.fromIterable` to iterate all item in List and `Subscribe` on  background Thread for doing background work then use `Map` operator to update your `Item` and do you long running work. After finish return what you need.

Sample code:

```
        Observable.fromIterable(itemList)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Function<Item, Item>() {
                @Override
                public Item apply(Item item) throws Exception {
                     item.setItemId("Id: " +  System.currentTimeMillis());
                      Log.i(TAG, "In Map Item: " + item.toString());
                      // do some long operation and return 

                     return item;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Item>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Item item) throws Exception {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Item: " + item.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will the long operation be applied to each items?

Comment: Yes it will applied to all item.

Comment: Thanks @Abu Yousuf. Will give a try!

Comment: How is accept() different from onNext()? I can also use onNext() here right.